# In MATLAB, define and color different regions of a shapefile

Tags: matlab

I have downloaded a shapefile that shows different regions (Identifiers) on a map (Equatorial, Tropical, Subtropical, Desert, Grassland, Temperate) according to the readme.txt file that came with it.

```
my_map = shaperead('my_shape_file.shp');
mapshow(my_map)
```

How do I define the different regions to enable me to color code them? I don't know how they are defined in the shapefile. The readme.txt file says "The identifiers are shown in the field titled Grid-code." I was expecting something like this to work:

```
zones = {my_map.Grid-code};
```

or

```
zone1 = {my_map.Tropical};
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: I think it depends on how your data looks, but I am not sure. The guess it that the identifiers are passed with each polygon.